# Prolog Member Implemention

Tags: list, search, prolog

I'm trying to implement my own version of member for something I'm working on. As of now it looks like this:

```
search(X,[X | T]).
search(X, [H | T]) :-
        search(X,T).
```

And it seems to work, however I have a few issues. I get a singleton warning on T and H. Also, I'm just not 100% sure on what the code actually does. From what I understand

```
search(X,[X | T]).
```

the first argument is my target, and the second argument is a list split into X and then everything else from list.

Then for

```
search(X, [H | T]) :-
            search(X,T).
```

I'm not really sure what is happening, besides it calling itself recursively. How does it actually know it's in the list? Any clarification would be appreciated.

EDIT: I think I get it now.

I'm saying the first line is true when the list just contains my target as a fact. Then, I recursively go through the list until the only thing that remains is my target, in which case it's true. If the list ends up empty that it would be false. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to understanding Prolog is to grok the declarative reading of the code. So forget *how* it's going to work for now and just think about what is logically being said.

```
search(X, [X|T]).
```

This says

> `search(X, [X|T])` is true *if* the first argument and the first item of the second argument are the same

The "if" portion there is just how the pattern matching works. You get a singleton variable warning because you never used `T`. Prolog would rather you wrote `search(X, [X|_])`.

The second line says

> `search(X, [H|T])` is *also* true *if* `search(X, T)` is true.

Your other singleton variable warning is here because you made a variable `H` and then didn't do anything with it, so Prolog would prefer to see `search(X, [_|T]) :- search(X, T).`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes! That was very helpful. I have another quick question that I'm not sure is worthy of a making another post. But pretty much how can I stop recursion from going back up the stack? Like all the predicates I need  to be true are true, but then it goes back up the stack where one fails, and therefore my entire predicate fails.

Comment: @NotSoTuringComplete you're still thinking procedurally: _how_ do I _do_ something. You need to think declaratively and forget about the mechanism by which it works. What you are trying to say is that you have computed something down in some recursive call but you don't have anywhere to stick it from the outermost call when you entered. The solution in Prolog is always going to be the same: add a variable for the result, and assign it only when you are complete (in the innermost level).

Comment: I think I figured out the logic but whenever I try and assign a value if the predicates I need are true it seems like it doesn't actually assign anything. When I print it just prints out _5412 or some other 4 digit number.

Comment: @NotSoTuringComplete That's definitely a variable with no value.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that a variable had to be assigned within a predicate, but I think I got it now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is great, I just want to clarify some things you added in your edit:

> I'm saying the first line is true when the list just contains my target as a fact. Then, I recursively go through the list until the only thing that remains is my target, in which case it's true. If the list ends up empty that it would be false. Is this correct?

The parts "... is true when the list *just* contains my target" and "until the *only thing* that remains is my target" (emphasis mine) are incorrect and suggest a small misunderstanding.

Rather, `search(a, [a, b, c])` is true because the target is *the first element* of the list in the second argument. Here `a` is **not** "the only thing that remains" in the list. It is just something that appears in the list in addition to other things that we don't need to care about.

You are correct about the last part: Yes, the search fails when it reaches the end of the list.

Comment: So, I'm saying it's true the first time that my head is the same as my target? And then if the list is empty it was never proven true and therefore it is false? Adjusting to Prolog has been a pain lol

Comment: Yes, exactly! The first clause succeeds when the list has a head and that head is equal to the target. And yes, this cannot succeed for the empty list since the empty list does not have a head.